# Which of 'Question on', 'question about', 'question regarding', 'question related to' is best?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, british-english

Which of these sentences are grammatically correct?

> - A: I have a few questions about this course.
> - B: I have a few questions on this course.
> - C: I have a few questions regarding this course.
> - D: I have a few questions related to this course.

Is B incorrect? Also, is the meaning of D identical to other sentences?

In general, do all of these have the same meaning? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A (*about*) and C (*regarding*) are synonymous. *About* is the most natural preposition, *regarding* is more stilted. They both indicate questions which concern the course itself, such as what topics will be covered, what time it takes place, what the prerequisites are, …

*Regarding* works better on narrower subjects. I have a question *about* mathematics, *regarding* continuous functions. *About* applies to a domain of knowledge, whereas *regarding* applies to a specific object or concept.

B (*on*) should mean the same as A and C, but it doesn't feel idiomatic in this sentence. I have a question *on* the grade you awarded me. I have a question *on* metaphysics. I'm having real trouble figuring out why *on* doesn't work in your example sentence.

D (*related*) has a wider meaning: it indicates questions that have something to do with the course. In particular, *related* includes questions about the subject matter of the course.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because questions is plural and also because it specifies "this". I have a question on the course sounds fine. I have a question on this course sounds wrong, as does I have questions on the course (the latter because it could also mean "I have questions literally on top of a physical course like a golf course").
I can't work out the rule either. I'm from England!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker. I think maybe it is that

"a question on" means: "a question on the topic of" and therefore can only be used when one can insert the phrase "the topic of" after the "on", while "a question about" can used before anything.

Example:

"I have a question on problem 5 in the homework assignment."

equals "I have a question on *the topic of* problem 5 in the homework assignment."

But in

"I have a question about problem 5 in the homework assignment.",

the question could also be about the wording of problem 5.

Please be kind, it's a guess from a learner only.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! It seems like folks are confused about whether you are asking another question or trying to answer this question. You may want to [edit] your answer to use statements instead of questions. It's OK to not be 100% certain, but you would want to use a phrase like "I think" instead of writing your answer as a series of questions.

Comment: @ColleenV thank you for the advice. It really was confusing.